# Product of even numbers divisible by $2012$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> For each positive integer $k$, $$f(k)=2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots2k.$$
>
> What is the least value of $k$ for which $f(k)$ is divisible by
>   $2012$?

I tried the factorisation and LCM and I don't know how to proceed

Answer (score 4):

Yes, factoring 2012 is a good start.

$$2012 = 2 * 2 * 503$$

Since $503$ is prime, what would be the smallest $k$ such that it appears in the expression?

Answer (score 3):

You say you tried factorisation. What did you get as the prime divisors of $2012$?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an old problem: Since $2012=4\cdot 503$, $k=503$...